# Java EE application custom compiling classloader

Tags: jsp, servlets, classloader, web-applications

Here are the requirements:

1. Java EE web application (in Tomcat)...
2. Dead simple, just JSP's, servlets and jars - no frameworks...
3. Nothing needs reloading, not the server, not the context, nothing...

The idea, so far, is to extend the WebappClassLoader (catalina.jar) to make your own custom classloader and register it in context.xml as a Loader element. With a bit of code you can write your classloader nicely, who will know where to find java source files and then compile them into class files, if needed, and then load them int memory, when asked to do so. The logic is plain and simple.

Except:

> How will Jasper know where to - automagically - find your classes, which have been generated by your custom classloader, so that it can compile JSPs that reference them, and even refresh them (your classes) on the fly? Is it impossible to achieve?

What do you think?

*(Please do not try to diverge the conversation by pointing to numerous existing frameworks that do take care of such things for you. The requirement is very specific: no frameworks, no nothing)*

Comment: Jasper's documentation stipulates that: "**JDT used to compile JSP pages** - The Eclipse JDT Java compiler is now used to perform JSP java source code compilation. This compiler loads source dependencies from the container classloader. Ant and javac can still be used.". So the question actually concerns the **"container classloader"**!

Comment: The container classloader is an instance of "**org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader**". It is the **Engine's** classloader. I do not see any obvious way to override/complement this to work automatically...

Answer (score 0):

One could add a classloader in the current web application context (context.xml):

```
<Context>
    <Loader loaderClass = "gr.nevma.cccl.CompilingClassLoader"/>
</Context>
```

And then create a classloader like:

```
package package gr.nevma.cccl;

import ...

public class CompilingClassLoader extends WebappClassLoader {

    public CompilingClassLoader ( ClassLoader parentClassLoader ) {

        super( parentClassLoader );

    }

    public Class<?> loadClass ( String className, boolean resolve ) throws ClassNotFoundException { 

        Class<?> theClass = null;

        // Do you stuff here
        return theClass;

    }

}
```

But this would only help if one wanted to be able to load classes explicitly from the classloader itself by calling ClassLoader::loadClass(...). This would not help in JSP compilation by Jasper. This means that when Jasper will try to compile JSP's that use classes which were to be loaded by this classloader the compilation would fail, because Jasper would not even ask this classloader to load any classes at all.

So, this way, automatic loading and reloading of classes can be achieved but in a - sort of - manual manner. These classes could be uniformly used throughout the whole web application, ie JSP pages!

Comment: Seems that the method getResourceAsStream() of the WebappClassLoader is called to load the classes that Jasper needs in order to compile JSP pages. In other words, when Jasper tries to compile JSP pages it requests the necessary classes form the classloader by calling getResourceAsStream(). So this method needs to be overriden to dynamically load whatever one needs to be loaded...

Comment: In order to be able to load and then reload any class (ie "define" it) one must delete and create anew its classloader. In other words, an instance of a classloader can only load (define) a class once! If the class needs to be actually reloaded (defined again) then a new classloader must be created for this job and the old one be deleted.

Comment: When a classloader has loaded a class once, it seems that the JVM never asks for this class from it again, at least not as long as the PermGen memory (where the classes are stored in RAM) is not full. So, this makes it inevitable that the classloader be deleted and be created anew in order to be able to reload the definition of a class. And this makes it even more clear that if references of a reloaded class remain hanging around, then the instance of the classloader that had loaded them will be left not garbage collected.

Comment: Also, by looking at the source code of Tomcat, in the JspCompilationContext class of Jasper, one can see that this is exactly what Jasper does in order to compile and reload JSP pages! It periodically checks JSP source files for changes and, if any changes are found, then it destroys its classloader, creates a new instance of it, compiles the JSP pages that need compiling and reloads them with the new instance of the classloader. 

And, yes, this indeed sounds like a "lot of work" for the server to do, if it set at a very often pace.